# MAVEN Assembly plugin

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

i am new to maven. I am trying to zip some content and put it in a desired location but while using the Assembly Plugin the zip file is getting created in the 'target' folder of my project. How can I save it in a desired location ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add below line to your pom.xml inside assembly plugin configuration

```
   <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>output/directory</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
```

For `outputDirectory` set the path where you want save your zip file.